# IIS - Execute a script/code snippet for every Request

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, iis-6, iis-5

I like to execute javascript/server side code for each and every request(`*.htm,*.asp,*.aspx,*.asmx, ...`) to IIS server.

Is there any way to write a isapi (dll) and register it with the iis that will accept all kind of request (`*.*`) and once my script is excuted, i will forward the request to appropriate isapi filter?

Answer (score 0):

HttpModule might be what you are looking for. You will register your HttpModule to web.config  and it will be added to pipeline, and will be executed for each request. But i dont think you can run javascript but you will be able to execute c# code on every request.

Here is msdn article , How to create HttpModule:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719858(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: http module can handle only aspx request, am i right? i have .asp , .htm also

Comment: @Muhammad http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112728/js-images-and-css-getting-intercepted-by-httpmodule