# Session not available in IHttpModule

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my program I'm trying to use session variable in  IHttpModule. Here is my code. This is working fine in VS 2010 development server. But when I try to debug in IIS7 it shows exception `System.Web.HttpException: Session state is not available in this context`
So why session not available  in IIS 7 but in development server.

```
using System;
using System.Web;

public class Globalizer : IHttpModule
{    
  public void Init(HttpApplication context)
  {
    context.AcquireRequestState += new EventHandler(setLanguage);
  }

  public void Dispose(){}

  public void setLanguage(Object sender, EventArgs i_eventArgs)
  {
    HttpApplication http_application = sender as HttpApplication;     
    http_application.Session["language"] = "test";

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason.

If is because `AcquireRequestState` trigger for the all files such as CSS, JS, images. those files are not having session.

solution: Seems there is a way to avoid calling  `IHttpModule` for all the request. ckeck this answer  [JS,Images and CSS getting intercepted by HTTPModule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112728/js-images-and-css-getting-intercepted-by-httpmodule).

But it didn't work for me. So I uses `HttpContext.Current.Session` instead of   `HttpApplication.Session` and every time it checks if Session is null before save to session.

**If some one knows, How to avoid calling `IHttpModule` for files other than `.aspx` Please help here.**

Here is the final code

```
using System;
using System.Web;

public class Globalizer : IHttpModule
{    
  public void Init(HttpApplication context)
  {
    context.AcquireRequestState += new EventHandler(setLanguage);
  }

  public void Dispose(){}

  public void setLanguage(Object sender, EventArgs i_eventArgs)
  {
    if(HttpContext.Current.Session != null){
      HttpContext.Current.Session["language"] = "test";
    }

  }
}
```

**Edit:** One other way is only use session if request comes to a `.aspx` file

```
HttpApplication http_application = sender as HttpApplication; 
HttpContext context = http_application.Context;
if(Path.GetExtension(context.Request.PhysicalPath) == ".aspx")
{
 HttpContext.Current.Session["language"] = "test";
 http_application.Session["language2"] = "test2";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need  is to implement [`IRequiresSessionState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.irequiressessionstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

So your code should look like:

```
public class Globalizer : IHttpModule, IRequiresSessionState
```

if all you use is reading Sessions (and never update them) then you should use [`IReadOnlySessionState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.ireadonlysessionstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as this last do not lock the session state, and therefor, you will not have concurrent requests).

Comment: balexandre: I thin Ravi's answer is the implementation of your answer. Is that the correct way to implement  `IRequiresSessionState`?

Answer (score 0):

If possible, move your handler to a [`PostAcquireRequestState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.postacquirerequeststate.aspx) handler:

> Occurs when the request state (for example, session state) that is associated with the current request has been obtained.

(Or an even later event)

The [`SessionStateModule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatemodule%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) itself loads session state in response to the [`AcquireRequestState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.acquirerequeststate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event - So at the moment, you're depending on whether your module or the session state module's handlers fire first.

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever- thank you for the idea. But it doesn't work. same exception. I'm wondering how my program works in development server?

Answer (score 0):

Found this over on the ASP.NET forums:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using System.Diagnostics;

// This code demonstrates how to make session state available in HttpModule,
// regradless of requested resource.
// author: Tomasz Jastrzebski

public class MyHttpModule : IHttpModule
{
   public void Init(HttpApplication application)
   {
      application.PostAcquireRequestState += new EventHandler(Application_PostAcquireRequestState);
      application.PostMapRequestHandler += new EventHandler(Application_PostMapRequestHandler);
   }

   void Application_PostMapRequestHandler(object source, EventArgs e)
   {
      HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)source;

      if (app.Context.Handler is IReadOnlySessionState || app.Context.Handler is IRequiresSessionState) {
         // no need to replace the current handler
         return;
      }

      // swap the current handler
      app.Context.Handler = new MyHttpHandler(app.Context.Handler);
   }

   void Application_PostAcquireRequestState(object source, EventArgs e)
   {
      HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)source;

      MyHttpHandler resourceHttpHandler = HttpContext.Current.Handler as MyHttpHandler;

      if (resourceHttpHandler != null) {
         // set the original handler back
         HttpContext.Current.Handler = resourceHttpHandler.OriginalHandler;
      }

      // -> at this point session state should be available

      Debug.Assert(app.Session != null, "it did not work :(");
   }

   public void Dispose()
   {

   }

   // a temp handler used to force the SessionStateModule to load session state
   public class MyHttpHandler : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
   {
      internal readonly IHttpHandler OriginalHandler;

      public MyHttpHandler(IHttpHandler originalHandler)
      {
         OriginalHandler = originalHandler;
      }

      public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
      {
         // do not worry, ProcessRequest() will not be called, but let's be safe
         throw new InvalidOperationException("MyHttpHandler cannot process requests.");
      }

      public bool IsReusable
      {
         // IsReusable must be set to false since class has a member!
         get { return false; }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Ravi: Not lucky, Actually I tried this before. same exception `System.Web.HttpException: Session state is not available in this context.`